# sendmail Name server timeout

Tags: linux, php, sendmail

Complete sendmail newbie here... I've been trying to get mailing to work in PHP and I've root caused it down to sendmail's complaint about "Name server timeout":

```
>sendmail -t -v
>From: help@me.com
>To: username@gmail.com
>.
gmail.com: Name server timeout
username@gmail.com... Transient parse error -- message queued for future delivery
username@gmail.com... queued
```

So it sounds like a DNS issue? But I can do a "dig mx gmail.com" and it will query successfully.

Here's what confuses me... I can get sendmail to work two other ways. The first way is through telnet:

```
>telnet 127.0.0.1 25
>Helo me
>Mail from: help@me.com
>Rcpt to: username@gmail.com
>.
message sent
```

And the second way is by explicitly appending the sendmail.cf, but this is strange because it's the exact same file I use to configure sendmail to begin with:

```
>sendmail -t -v -C/etc/mail/sendmail.cf
```

But none of these solutions will resolve my PHP mailing... I am clueless as to what is going on... appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, after three days I finally solved it... I don't know how much this'll apply to anyone out there cuz it's such a corner case.

So I'm working in a chrooted environment of Ubuntu on Android. When you access any type of socket in Ubuntu (sendmail, mysql, etc) your process needs to be running in group 3003 (AID_INET) or root and that's because android forces this (CONFIG_ANDROID_PARANOID_NETWORK). The reason why it worked with telnet was cuz I was root, the same reason why it worked by appending -C (-C forces sendmail to run under root...)

My lightbulb starting going off when I noticed that I could not resolve any hostnames unless I was root (ping, wget, dig,), which is a permissions issue.

SOOOO solution is to create a group called aid_inet and give it 3003, then add anything that requires sockets to that group

```
groupadd -g 3003 aid_inet
usermod -G aid_inet user
```

It is now one of my deepest wishes that this info will save some poor lost soul in the future from breaking his head on the table as I did...